# How to give potion effects to everyone on a certain team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm making a kind of kit PVP game called classes, where you join a team, let's say, the barbarian. You can't hit any other barbarians, and it shows everyone else with the same class. But I want people with certain classes to have special effects how do I do that?

I tried:

```
/effect 1 1000000 5 @a[barbarian]
```

But it didn't work. I am running 1.9

Comment: Check the wikis before posting an answer. `http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selector_arguments` would have told you what you were doing wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry. I looked everywhere for the answer but I could not find it no matter how hard I tried. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If you're ever wondering anything about *minecraft*, the *minecraft wiki* might just be the place to look :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selector parameters consist of a unique key name and a value, separated by an equals sign, with each unique parameter separated by a comma. The `team` parameter is what allows you to target players based on their team. For the `/effect` command, the target comes first:

```
/effect <player> <effect> [seconds] [amplifier] [hideParticles]
/effect @a[team=barbarian] minecraft:speed 1000000 5
```

See also, [Minecraft Wiki: Target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

Answer (score 0):

*/effect @a[team=**teamname**] 1 1000000 5* would set an effect to all players on a certain team, where **teamname** is the name of the team that you want to give the effect to.

Comment: What was wrong with this answer? Is there anything that I need to add? @Kylun11